# How do I run the MainActivity when I start a Service?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service

I'm pretty new in Java/Android Studio (and just created an account here), so apologies in advance if I say/write something wrong.

So I have the following problem, I have this MainActivity.java (just a part of the code below):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

public static final MediaType FORM_DATA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
//URL derived from form URL
public static final String URL = "...";
//input element ids found from the live form page
public static final String LAT="entry_1903202747";
public static final String LONG="entry_1549783406";
public static final String MOD="entry_1161588883";
public static final String MAN="entry_852582911";
public static final String IMEI="entry_738564261";
public static final String EXIP="entry_1256979126";
public static final String ACC="entry_1601482207";

private Context context;

LocationManager locationmanager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    context=this;

    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    final TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    final TextView textView12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    final TextView textView13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    final TextView textView14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    final TextView textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    final TextView textView15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);


    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                PostDataTask postDataTask = new PostDataTask();

            postDataTask.execute(URL,textView3.getText().toString(),textView5.getText().toString(),textView12.getText().toString(),textView13.getText().toString(),textView14.getText().toString(),textView7.getText().toString(),textView15.getText().toString());

        }
    });
```

and I have a MyService.java:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

*EDIT

The current application sends data to a Google Form when pressed the "Submit" button, but I want the application to send the data when it runs in the background, without pressing the "Submit" button.

So when I start the activity (only pressing once on the "start activity button") it needs to start sending data to the form. Hope this clears things up, if not, i'll try to explain it even further.

I want something like this (MyService.java):

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                PostDataTask postDataTask = new PostDataTask();

            postDataTask.execute(URL,textView3.getText().toString(),textView5.getText().toString(),textView12.getText().toString(),textView13.getText().toString(),textView14.getText().toString(),textView7.getText().toString(),textView15.getText().toString());

        }
    });

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The main goal is to execute "postDataTask" (from MainAcitivy) in MyService

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "run the code within in MainActivity" means.

Comment: I pasted a part of my "code" in the MainActivity. So I want the whole "code" to run when I start the service.

Comment: I think it depends on what the "code" does. If it collects some data from form, then you can save these data to somewhere when activity comes to background (event use static variable) and the service can read these data later. If the "code" does some utility function, you could move them to Utils class.

Comment: The whole code in MainActivity exists of: getting phone location/IMEI/etc. -> insert into google form --> results in google spreadsheet ;

Comment: Why did you put that code into `MainActivity` in the first place? Create an `IntentService` and put that code in `onHandleIntent()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably extend off intentService instead so it can send data out on another thread so you dont slow down the UI.  But if you need the service to hang around then your approach is ok but im not clear what your goal is.  Anyway your exact question is

> How do I run the MainActivity when I start a Service?

. A service is a type of context so you can start an activity from it.   do this:

```
@Override 
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{ 
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: I don't know how, but you managed to understand what I want ;D Thank you !

Comment: Great news. if your able to accept the answer do so, so others know its resolved and discontinue there effort.

Comment: still new with all of this, but thanks for the info! (accepted the answer)